# Is the "be" redundant here?

Tags: grammar, be

Is the use of "be" in the following sentence incorrect?

> "I have never before heard that be said."

Comment: Would be "been" but, yes, redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Question:  Is the use of "be" in the following sentence incorrect?
"I have never before heard that be said."

Yes, the use of "be" in that sentence is incorrect.  Below are suggested ways to state the sentence correctly.  Explanation or action taken is in [ ].

1. I have never before heard that said. 
   [The "be" is removed.  The sentence sounds awkward though.]

1a. I have never heard that said before. 
[A derivative of No. 1, this version is less awkward because "before" has been moved to the end of the sentence.]

2. I have never before heard that being said. 
   ["be" is changed to "being."]

2a. I have never heard that being said before. 
[A derivative of no. 2, the sentence is now easier to read after moving "before" to the end of the sentence.]

Answer (score 0):

We have one option to save the poster's sentence from bordering on ungrammatical by viewing it in the subjunctive mood. We rephrase the sentence like this:

- I have never before heard (that), that(= it) be said.

When we describe known objective facts we use 'indicative mood' and when we don't we use English subjunctive. Wikipedia says Subjunctive is used for statement of one's state of mind such as opinion, belief, purpose, intention or desire or something contrary to fact. In modern English Subjunctive has fallen into disue except the use of third person singular without 's',and always 'BE' in present and no use of 'do' in present negative. Where required, "Be" is always "WERE" in past form. However, in a sense, SUBJUNCTIVE is irrealis and tenseless. Thanks to AmE that has still kept SUBJUNCTIVE alive. Sometimes, Subjunctive is soothing to the ear, solace to the heart.

To my mind it is the subjunctive use of BE and, as such, grammatical.

Comment: Maybe grammatical ... definitely archaic, even in AmE.

Comment: @Peter Shor I am referring to the use of subjunctive in general and have tried to justify an otherwise awkward usage. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Even without the 'be', the corrected version would be archaic, due to the unusual position of 'before'. I'd suggest;

> I've never heard that said before.